# Mercurial Eclipse Plugin Installation Error

Tags: eclipse

I am trying ti install Mercurial Eclipse plugin by using help>add new softwares...entering URL:"https://bitbucket.org/mercurialeclipse/update-site/raw/default/" Once I accept the agreement and start the installation it stucks in the middle showing error message as: "Installing Software has encountered a problem. An error occurred while collecting items to be installed." Can someone help me with it? Thanks.

Comment: You should open the "Error Log" (via Window -> Show View) and look what messages have been logged there.

Comment: The message is: An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session context was:(profile=epp.package.cpp,phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=). Artifact not found: http://mercurialeclipse.eclipselabs.org.codespot.com/files/com.nexj.oss.MercurialEclipseReviewBoard_1.1.0.201304290949.jar.

Comment: I have figured it out.